# Java grouping by back to List of objects?

Tags: java

I have a simple pojo:

```
class Pojo
{
   string key;
   int value;
}
```

This is in a list:

```
List<Pojo> myList;
```

I can have multiple values per key, so for example:

```
A 5
A 7
B 3
```

So I want to group by the key and sum the values and put it back into a `List<Pojo>` with a single entry for A 12, B 3, etc.

This is what I have right now:

```
myMap.get("xxx")
  .values()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pojo::getKey), Collectors.summingLong(Pojo::getValue))
```

This gets me a `Map<String, Int>`.

Do I need to do something like:

```
myMap.get("xxx")
  .values()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pojo::getKey), Collectors.summingLong(Pojo::getValue))
    .entrySet().stream.map((entry) -> new Pojo(..)).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Or is there a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: wouldn't see how to make this more conscise. I just think you can use the method reference syntax for creating pojos, `Pojo::new`

Comment: Try [`Collectors::reducing`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing(T,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) instead of [`Collectors::summingLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingLong(java.util.function.ToLongFunction)).

Answer (score 0):

It should work when using `Collectors::reducing`.

```java
myMap.get("xxx").values().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pojo::getKey, Collectors.reducing(
        new Pojo(null, 0),
        (a, b) -> new Pojo(b.getKey(), a.getValue() + b.getValue())))
    .values()
```

The call to `groupingBy` would return a `Map<String, List<Pojo>>`, but providing a *reducing collector* as second argument to `groupingBy` takes the values of the list and reduces them to a single element. The result is a `Map<String, Pojo>`, and in order to get a `Collection<Pojo>`, we simply need to call `values()` on the `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it. Sometimes the simplest is the best and most efficient. Here is one of them.

```
List<Pojo> list = List.of(new Pojo("A", 5), new Pojo("B", 3),
        new Pojo("A", 7), new Pojo("C", 10), new Pojo("B", 12));

Map<String, Pojo> map = new HashMap<>();
```

The way this works is as follows:

- it requires a simple setter in your class to set the value.
- Iterate thru the list and if the map doesn't contain it, add it.
- else use the just retreived object and add its value and the current object's value and set the sum in the Map's version of the object.  So the map maintains a tally of the update without replacing the object in the map.

```
for (Pojo p : list) {
    Pojo cp;
    if ((cp = map.get(p.getKey())) != null) {
        cp.setValue(cp.getValue() + p.getValue());
    } else {
        map.put(p.getKey(), p);
    }
}
```

This next step could be eliminated if you don't mind working with type `Collection`.

```
List<Pojo> results = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

Now print them

```
results.forEach(Sytem.out::println);
```

Prints

```
A 12
B 15
C 10
```

On the other hand, if you prefer streams this works sans a setter. But it does create a new object to replace the old one.

```
Map<String, Pojo> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Pojo::getKey, s -> s,
                (a, b) -> new Pojo(a.getKey(),
                        a.getValue() + b.getValue())));

map.values().forEach(Sytem.out::println);

    
The pojo class
```

class Pojo {
String key;
int value;

```
public Pojo(String key, int value) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;       
}

public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setValue(int v) {
    this.value = v;
}
public String toString() {
    return key + " " + value;
}
```

}